# Can not reenable Bluetooth from System Settings after disabling Airplane mode

Tags: bluetooth, system-settings, 21.04, airplane-mode

After deactivating Airplane Mode, I can not re-enable Bluetooth from System Settings.

I would like Bluetooth to be reactivated from System Settings:

- When Airplane Mode is deactivated
- Or, when I click the Bluetooth toggle button in the header bar

How can I achieve this?

**Sequence of Steps**

1. Enable Airplane Mode by pressing the <kbd>✈ F12</kbd> key.

   - Airplane mode is enabled [expected]
   - WiFi is disabled [expected]
   - Bluetooth is disabled [expected]

     ```
     sudo rfkill list all
     1: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: yes
         Hard blocked: no
     2: hci0: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: yes
         Hard blocked: no
     ```
2. Disable Airplane Mode from System Settings by clicking the Airplane Mode toggle button.

   - Airplane mode is disabled [expected]
   - WiFi is enabled, and automatically connects to my network [expected]
   - Bluetooth stays disabled [UNEXPECTED]

     ```
     sudo rfkill list all
     1: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
     2: hci0: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
     ```
3. Attempt to re-enable Bluetooth from System Setting

   - Click the Bluetooth toggle button in the header bar
   - Bluetooth stays disabled [UNEXPECTED]

Sometimes, I can reactivate Bluetooth from the command line.

This doesn't always work, and my goal is to get it to work from the System Settings GUI.

```
systemctl restart bluetooth
```

**System Information**

Bluetooth and WiFi Adapters:

```
lsusb | grep Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface

lspci | grep Network
3b:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

Operating System:

- Ubuntu 21.04

  ```
  uname -r
  5.11.0-16-generic

  dpkg -l bluez
  5.56-0ubuntu4
  ```

Laptop:

- HP Spectre x360 Convertible 15-bl1XX
- There is no physical WiFi or Bluetooth switch on this machine
- The <kbd>✈ F12</kbd> key enables/disables Airplane Mode (although disabling doesn't always work)

Comment: This just happened to me today! Your `systemctl bluetooth restart` got me moving again, so thanks for that, but I've no idea on the underlying problem sorry. Hopefully someone in the know chimes in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved for me using:

- Ubuntu 21.10.
- Linux Kernel 5.13.0-20-generic

When I press the the Airplane Mode button on my laptop, or toggle "on" Airplane Mode from System Settings, both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth both turn *off as expected*.

Then, when I press the the Airplane Mode button on my laptop again, or toggle "off" Airplane Mode from System Settings, both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth turn *on as expected*.

If you are experiencing this issue, you may be able to upgrade to Linux Kernel 5.13.0-20-generic. However, is it also possible this was an issue with Ubuntu 21.04 / Gnome 3.38, in which case you will need to upgrade to 21.10 in order to fix the problem.