# Gnome Bluetooth settings stuck off, display is inconsistent

Tags: 20.04, gnome, bluetooth

On 20.04, if I open Settings > Bluetooth, the toggle sometimes kind of works, but bluetooth appears to remain off. See screenshots below.

`rfkill list` seems ok:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I tried the plausible answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787023/bluetooth-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts) but no luck.

[image: popover]

[image: settings panel]

Comment: I had a similar situation after activating Airplane mode: [Can not reenable Bluetooth from System Settings after disabling Airplane mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337179/can-not-reenable-bluetooth-from-system-settings-after-disabling-airplane-mode). Sometimes `systemctl bluetooth restart` seems to restart Bluetooth.